# DiscordJS Error - ReferenceError: member is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I try to execute this code (for a warn system in Discord.JS), I have this error
`ReferenceError: member is not defined`

```
    name: 'warn',
    description: 'Pour warn un membre',
    execute(message, args, Client){

        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Tu n'as pas les permissions de warn un membre");
        if(message.channel.type == "dm") return;
            let mention = message.mentions.members.first();
            const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') 
            if(mention == undefined){
                message.reply("Membre non-menntionné ou mal mentionné");
            }
            else {
                if (!reason) return message.channel.send("Veuillez indiquer une raison")        
                if (!Client.warn.warns[member.id]) Client.warn.warns[member.id] = []
                Client.warn.warns[member.id].unshift({
                    reason,
                    date: Date.now(),
                    mod: message.author.id
                })
                fs.writeFileSync('./commands/bdd/warns.js', JSON.stringify[Client.warn])
                message.channel.send(`${member} a été warn pour ${reason}`)
            }           
    },
};
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you do a console.log(message), console.log(args) and console.log(Clients) to see what you get from every one of those variables ? It seems that you are not able to access the message.member. Maybe it is message[0].member.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your member as `mention`, in the line:
`let mention = message.mentions.members.first();`, however, you use `member` in for example `if (!Client.warn.warns[member.id])`. If you change all the `member` which should be `mention` to `mention`, it's fixed :)